# Matplotlib - Adding Text inside a graph - pyplot.text()

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to learn how to use the pyplot.text() function from Matplotlib in order to be able to add text in my graphs.In the below code the function does not seem to work.I am not sure why.Could someone please help me?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lista=[10,20,25,30,30,40,50,60,70,80,40,60,80,90]
listb=[1400,1500,1700,1600,1500,1450,1400,1400,1600,1600,1500,1500,1700,1700]
listz=[140,100,130,110,10,20,40,30,100,50,90,60,80,70]

plt.scatter(lista,listb,s=listz,marker="o",color="#FFDD44",alpha=0.7)

plt.text(1500,80,"Correct!",fontsize=20,color="#FFDD44")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you mean `plt.text(80,1500...)` by chance?

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what these number refer to? I was just putting random numbers.

Comment: Try the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) :-)

Comment: Good idea! Thanks!